# How to print a form in vb.net 2010?

Tags: vb.net, forms, printing

I would like to print a form with a scrollable datagridview table. But I'm getting an empty file in *.docx.

Comment: Can you post your code and error logs (if any)?

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN - PrintForm Component (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb690938.aspx)

```
' For Direct Printing to a Printer
Dim pf As New PrintForm
pf.Form = Me
pf.PrintAction = PrintToPrinter
pf.Print()
```

See [MSDN - Print a Form by Using the PrintForm Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629268%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)  for Print to File options.